# what are the different type of design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

hey guys, recently i worked on `Repository Pattern` in aspnet MVC and i was just wondering that,i mean how many different patterns are out there (i.e alternative to Repository Pattern)? please i need small explanation of each Patterns available..? and among all those Patterns what you'll recommend me to go for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244706/learning-implementing-design-patterns-for-newbies, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449731/design-patterns-to-avoid, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105049/what-are-the-best-design-patterns-books-you-have-read, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974/what-design-patterns-do-you-use-most-often

Comment: Please try not to write like you talk. Your question seems very confused. Have you tried looking some alternatives up yourself?

Comment: ya i search'd on google, i found singleton and Factory method etc on wikipedia but these are not alternative to `Repository pattern`

Comment: There are many strong opinions about singletons.  Many of those opinions boil down to "They're bad, and just glorified globals."  You should at least consider that argument.

Comment: There are many patterns, do you want us to list all of them with practical examples? Martin Fowler's Pattern of Enterprise Application Architecture already has many patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not heard of the Repository Pattern, so it is not part of the [GoFs initial set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns). A quick [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Repository+pattern+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-GB%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) shows it to be part of [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/)s [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) (a good book I seam to recall, but way to many patterns to keep in ones head).
Looking over the [index](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/index.html) for PoEAA and the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) lives in the *Object-Relational Metadata Mapping Patterns* subset. The alternatives specified in PoEAA are:

- [Metadata Mapping](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html)
- [Query Object](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/queryObject.html)

however other pattern repositories may include other options.

Answer (score -1):

GOF patterns a basically categorized into 4, which are creational pattern, behavioural parttern and structural pattern.

Comment: You say 4, but there are only 3 in your answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

There are 23 different known design patterns, and they can be separated into three categories by their purpose: Creational, Structural, and Behavioral.

[image: Different design patterns]

Read more in this article I wrote: [JavaScript Design Patterns: Creational](https://szaranger.medium.com/javascript-design-patterns-creational-9d9105c39e5)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.