# Use prototype pattern or not

Tags: php, design-patterns, prototype-pattern

I have a question. I need to create a little thing to do with products. Now I can have say 7 different types of products. Some are subtypes of others e.g.

```
Cars
 - Vans
   - petrol
   - diesel
 - City
 - Hatchback
 - Saloon
 - Estate
   - petrol
   - diesel
```

Now, for the sake of the argument all my City, Hatchback and Saloon cars are hybrid/gas/whatever and I do not plan to sell petrol and diesel ones. However there is a possibility that I may have petrol and diesel saloon cars sometime in the future, but it's not like I am going to have 20+ types of products. If it is going to go up  I will have probably 2-3 more types.

From what I understand `Prototype Pattern` may be good one here for I will be able to avoid duplication between estate->petrol and van->petrol ... but then again Van cars will have different characteristics than say city car e.g. maximum loading dimensions.

I have been reading extensively about design patterns and one thing I remember for certain is not to use pattern when you don't need it. Now the question is - do I need it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Decorator Pattern is probably the most straight forward one to use and would be a good one to extend concrete objects functionality and/or characteristics.

Here is some light reading: [Head First Design Patterns - CH3 pdf](http://oreilly.com/catalog/hfdesignpat/chapter/ch03.pdf)

FYI, couple must have's for learning and referencing design patterns regardless your language of choice:

1) [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

2) [Patterns for Enterprise Application Architecture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321127420)

3) [Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612)

And sites:

1) [DoFactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx)

2) [StackOverflow Design Patterns Newbie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244706/learning-implementing-design-patterns-for-newbies)

There are a few others, I'll have to dig them up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I don't want to extend object's functionality as it will be pretty much set throughout the runtime, but I want to model classes in a way that will be different than straight inheritance.

Comment: Regardless I accept this answer for it has nice links to valuable resources :)

Answer (score 1):

Does each type of car requires different behaviour? A petrol van acts different from a diesel van? A Saloon has to *behave* different than an Estate?

If I understand correctly, you need something like that

```
public enum FuelType
{
     Petrol,
     Diesel
}

public class Car
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public FuelType Fuel {get;set;}
}

public class Van:Car { } 
public class CityCar:Car { }
```

If the characterstics of a Van are just different values than a Car, you don't need subclassing, you need to change just a property value. A Van for example should have other properties or a differnt implementation of methods to be eligible for subclassing.