# Entity Framework ( Questions on POCO, Context, and DTO)

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, poco

I have been reading about entity framework over the past couple of days and have managed to get a fair idea of using it but I still have a couple of questions some of which might seem a bit too basic. For perspective I am using entity framework 4.0 in an asp.net web application.If you can answer any of the questions please go ahead.

1. What advantage do I get by using POCO templates. I understand that if I wish to get persistence ignorance and keep my Entities clear of any information related to storage POCO entities are the way to go. Also I could switch from Entity framework to say NHibernate with relative ease when using POCO entities? Apart from loose coupling is there any significant reason for me to go towards POCO entities. Also if I do use POCO do I end up losing anything. I still get change tracking and lazy loading with the help of proxies?
2. Is it normal practice to use the Entities of the EF model as Data transfer Objects or Business Objects. i.e for example I have a separate class library for my entity model.Supposing I am using MVP , where I want a list of Employee's in a company. The presenter would request my business logic functions which would query the entity model for the list of Employee's and return the list of entities to the presenter. In this case my presenter would need to have a reference to the EF model. Is this the correct way? In the case of my asp.net web applciation it shouldnt be a problem but if I am using web services how does this work? Is this the reason to go towards POCO entities?
3. Supposing The Employee entity has a navigation property to a company table. If I use and wrap the data context in an 'using' block , and try to access the navigation property in the BL I am assuming I would get an exception. Would I also get an exception if I turned off lazyloading and used the 'include' linq query to get the entity? On a previous post someone recommended I use an context per request implying that the context remains active even when I am in the BL. I am assuming I would still need to detach the object and attach it to the context on my next request if I wish to persist any changes I make? or Instead should I just query for the object again with the new context and update it?
4. This question has more to do with organizing files/best practices and is a followup to a question i posted earlier. When I am using separate files based on entities to organize my data access layer, what is the best practice to organize my queries involving joins between multiple tables. I am still a bit hazy on organization. Have tried searching online but havent had much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terrific question.  My first recommendation is to think in patterns.  With that said...

1. You pretty much nailed the advantages of using POCO.  There are some distinct advantages to decoupling your business objects (POCO entities) from your data access layer.  But the primary reason is like you said the ability to change or modify layers below.  However using POCO you are essentially following the Code First (CF) approach.  Personally, I consider it Code In Parallel depending upon your software development life cycle.  You still have all the bells and whistles that data or model first approach have and some since you can extend the DbContext which is ObjectContext under the hood.  I read an article, which I cannot seem to find, that CF is the future of Entity Framework.  Lastly the nice thing with POCO is you are able to incorporate validation rules here or else where.  You can also provide projections.  Lets say you have Date of Birth but you want an Age property as well.  That now becomes a no brainer as the Age property is ignored when mapping to the database.
2. Personally I create my own business objects (POCO) for large projects that tend to have a life of its own where change is a way of life.  Another thought is scalability and maintainability.  What if down the road I choose to split functionality between applications where, like you mentioned web services, functionality is now delivered from two disparate locations.  If you have encapsulated your business objects and DAL within the same code block separation or scalability has now become a bit more complex.  However, consider the project.  It may be small with very little future change so no need to throw a grenade to kill a fly.  At which time data first might be the way to go and let edmx file represent your objects.  So don't marry yourself to one technology or one methodology/pattern.  Do what makes sense for your time and business.
3. Using statements are perfectly fine.  In fact I've recently been turned on to then wrapping that within a TransactionScope.  If an error occurs rollbacks are inherent.  Next, something to consider is the UnitOfWork.  UnitOfWork pattern encapsulates a snapshot of what needs to be performed where the Data Context is the boundaries from which you work within.  For each UnitOfWork you have a subject for which work is to be performed on.  For example an Employee.  So if you are to save Employee information to keep it simple you would make a call to the BL service or repository (which ever).  There you pass in the Employee Id, perform some work under that UnitOfWork where it is either instantiated in the constructor or using Dependency Injections (DI or IoC).  Easy starter is StructureMap.  There the service makes the necessary calls to your UnitOfWork (DbContext) then returns control back upstream (e.g. UI).
4. The best way to learn here is to view others code.  I'd start with some Microsoft examples.  I'd start with Nerd Dinner (http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) then build off that.

Additional Reading:

[Use prototype pattern or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925943/use-prototype-pattern-or-not/7926361#7926361)

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

[EDIT]
NightHawk457, I'm terribly sorry for not responding to your questions.  Hopefully you figured it out but for future readers...

To help everyone visualize, imagine the below Architecture using the Domain Model and Repository as an example.  Remember, there are many ways to skin a cat so take this and make it your own and don't forget my Grenade comment above.

- **Data Layer** (*Data Access*): MyDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork, where IUnitWork contracts the CRUD operations.
- **Data Repository** (*Data Access / Business Logic*): MyDomainObjectRepository : IMyDomainObjectRepository, which receives IUnitOfWork by Factory class or Dependency Injection. Calls MyDomainObject validation on CRUD operations.
- **Domain Model** (*Business Logic*): MyDomainObject using [Custom] Validation Attributes.  Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236415.aspx) for pros/cons.
- **MVVM / MVC / WCF** (*Presentation / Service Layers*): What ever additional layers you chose, you now have access to your data which is wrapped nicely in smaller modules who are self encapsulating of their function.  The presentation layer (e.g. ViewModel, Controller, Code-Behind, etc.) can then receive an IMyObjectRepository by a Factory class or by Dependency Injection.

**Tips:**

- Pass connection string into MyDbContext so you can reuse MyDbContext.
- MySql does not play well with System.Transactions.TransactionScope, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774719/how-do-i-use-transactionscope-with-mysql-and-entity-framework-getting-multiple).  I  don't recall exactly but it was something MySql did not support.  This makes Testing a bit difficult since we have created this level of separation.
- Create a Test project for each layer and at the minimum test general functionality/rules.
- Each Domain Object should extend base object with ID field at minimum.  Also do not implement Key attributes here.  Domain Object should not describe architecture but rather the specific data as an entity.  Even on Code First this can be achieved by the Fluent API.
- Think generics when creating MyDbContext. ;)  Read Diego's [post](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/04/conventions-in-entity-framework-41.html).
- In ASP.NET, the repositories are nice to use with ObjectDataSources.

As you can see, there is clear separation of roles where IUnitOfWork and IMyDomainObjectRepository are the Interfaces which expose the above layers functionality.  And as an example, IUnitOfWork could be NHibernate, Entity Framework, LinqToSql or ADO.NET where a change to the factory class or dependency injection registration is all that has to change.  FYI, I've heard the Repository called the Service Layer as well.  Personally I like the first name to not be confused with Web Services.  The next big take away from this structure is realizing the scope for you Database Context (IUnitOfWork).  A simple example would be a ASP.NET page where for each page there is one and only one IUnitOfWork for either each repository or for that scope of work.  Same holds true for ViewModels, Controllers, etc.  So let's say you need to utilize two repositories, EmployeeRepository and HRRepository.  You then could share the IUnitOfWork between both or not.  To cross page, ViewModel or Controller boundaries, we use the ID for entities where they are then pulled from the DB and work is performed.  You could alternatively pass a DTO across boundaries and attach to the context but then you begin losing separation of layers.

To continue, POCO classes do not have to be auto generated.  In fact you can create your Entity Classes from scratch and perform the mapping in your extended DbContext class inside the OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder mb) method.  Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), then [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx) and note the Additional Resources, google Fluent API and read this [post](http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2011/04/conventions-in-entity-framework-41.html) by Diego.

As for validation, this is an interesting point because it would be GREAT if all Business Rules could be validated in one location.  Well, as we all know that doesn't work real well. So here is my recommendation, keep all data level validation (i.e. required, range, format, etc.) with data annotation as much as possible in the domain object and leave process validation in the Repository with clear roles of the Repository (i.e. if (isEmployee) do this, else that).  I say clear, such that you do not want to add an Employee in two different Repositories where validation has to be duplicated.  To call the validation, start [here](http://blog.jorgef.net/2011/01/odata-dataannotations.html).  Capture the ValidationResults and send upstream with a MyRepositoryValidationException which contains a collection of validations errors (e.g. Employee is required) which can be presented to the presentation layer.  With all that said, don't forget to perform validation at the presentation layer.  You don't want post backs to make sure an Employee has a valid Email, for example.

Just remember to balance time and effort with complexity.  For something simple, use Data First or Model First with your EDMX file.  Then lay a repository on top of that which also contains all the validation rules.

Comment: Using POCO's is NOT code first.  You can have POCO's in database first and model first.  Code First refers only to the way the model is defined.  In Code First, this is done with fluent mappings, in database and model first, this is done with a .edmx file.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I am looking into the UnitOfWork and RepositoryPatterns. Will probably be able to comment better on 3 only after some reading. Also regarding adding validation to POCO classes I am assuming you are talking about validation through data annotations? I am assuming you would have to use partial classes here since if the POCO classes are auto generated we would lose the validation if its in the same class. I will have to do some reading up on this too but if I am way off track on this how do you do validation?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Mystere Man.  And to extend your point and further correct myself, we can also extend generated objects by using partial classes.