# How do I use TransactionScope with MySql and Entity Framework? (getting Multiple simultaneous connections...are not currently supported error)

Tags: .net, mysql, entity-framework-4, transactions

I have a new .NET 4.0 console application that uses:

- MySql 6.4.4.0
- Entity Framework 4.2 (code-first)
- Visual Studio 2010

So far this works. I can add and read from the database fine.

Now, when I add TransactionScope, as in the following example:

```
public static void TestInsert()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            // Create a test user
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            var user1 = new User { UserID = 1, UserName = "test" };
            context.Users.Add(user1);  <-- exception occurs here

            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the error:

**Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported.**

It seems that even the latest version of MySql does not like TransactionScope working with EntityFramework.

I want to be able to use transactions, especially in test projects so that I can roll back any changes.

Any idea how I can fix this or work around it?

**Full error information**

```
System.Data.DataException was unhandled
  Message=An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<InitializeDatabase>b__4(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
InnerException: System.Data.EntityException
   Message=The underlying provider failed on Open.
   Source=System.Data.Entity
   StackTrace:
        at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
        at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
        at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
        at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
        at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
        at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
        at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
        at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.QueryForModelHash()
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
        at System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel(Boolean throwIfNoMetadata)
        at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass5.<PerformDatabaseInitialization>b__3()
        at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
    InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
        Message=Multiple simultaneous connections or connections with different connection strings inside the same transaction are not currently supported.
        Source=MySql.Data
        StackTrace:
             at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
             at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation, Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)
        InnerException:
```

**Some of the classes (nothing complicated):**

```
[Table("User")]
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
    }

    // Primary key
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("DbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Tell Code First to ignore PluralizingTableName convention
        // If you keep this convention then the generated tables will have pluralized names.
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

**App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DbContext" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=****; Uid=****; Pwd=****;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to use `TransactionScope`? Because EF `Context` updates the database in a single transaction.

Comment: I want to use TransactionScope for a couple of reasons: 1) Inside each unit test I want to restore the database after the test is completed (method promoted by "The Art of Unit Testing" by Roy Osherove). I am open to better suggestions. 2) I find that I have to SaveChanges in order for subsequent queries to pick up those changes plus I call multiple self-contained operations in the Data Access Layer. I need the Business Layer to put multiple independent operations under a single transaction. Again, I am open to suggestions here.

Comment: @DanC Did you found anything to fix the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find a reliable answer so I gave up on using TransactionScope. Instead, and perhaps better in the long run, I ended up creating an interface to the DbContext so that I could use a mock in unit tests and didn't write to the database at all. For real writing to the database, the DbContext save changes should act as a transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Create transaction after creating context.

```
public static void TestInsert()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // Create a test user
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            var user1 = new User { UserID = 1, UserName = "test" };
            context.Users.Add(user1); 

            context.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly complete the scope.

> The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
>
> Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.

```
 scope.Complete();
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).